# No sound in Android TTS - wrong context?

Tags: java, android, android-context, google-text-to-speech

I have a class `DistanceAnnouncer`, which uses Android Text-to-speech engine to announce distance between two locations. It is constructed like this:

```
public class DistanceAnnouncer {
    private TextToSpeech speaker;

    public DistanceAnnouncer(Context context) {
        speaker = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() { 
        ...
```

Distance is spoken to user by this method:

```
public void speak(Location targetLocation, Location currentLocation) {
   float distanceInMeters = targetLocation.distanceTo(currentLocation);
   speaker.speak(String.valueOf(distanceInMeters) + " meters",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
```

In my `MainActivity` I create a class-level object...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    distanceAnnouncer = new DistanceAnnouncer(this);
```

Which is then used in anonymous method when clicking a Dialog button as shown below. This works fine. But now I want to refactor code to use less memory and want to get rid of class-level variable. To test it I created a new test object and gave it `MainActivity.this` as a Context (as opposed to class-level object which in constructor receives `this`). The old object still works, new one is not. There are no exceptions thrown. Code is executed but there is no sound.

Code:

```
    public void NewTargetButtonClicked(View view) {
        final EditText entryEditText = new EditText(this);

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.enter_coordinates_prompt);
        alert.setView(entryEditText);
        alert.setCancelable(true);
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (entryEditText.getText() == null) return;

                Location newLocation = getLocationFromCoords(entryEditText.getText().toString());
                //pagaidām protam apstrādāt tikai decimālgrādus
                if (!(newLocation == null)) {
                    mTargetLocation = newLocation;
                    refreshDistance();
                    Button targetButton = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.newTargetButton);
                    targetButton.setText(R.string.set_new_target);

                    DistanceAnnouncer newDistanceAnnouncer = new DistanceAnnouncer(MainActivity.this);
                    //THIS DOESN'T WORK:                    
                    newDistanceAnnouncer.speak(mTargetLocation,mCurrentLocation);

                    //THIS WORKS:
                    distanceAnnouncer.speak(mTargetLocation,mCurrentLocation);

                    CheckBox speakCheckbox = (CheckBox) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.speakDistanceCheckbox);
                    speakCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

I suspect this is context problem, but what in this case is the difference between two contexts? They should be the same, shouldn't they?

EDIT: Full DistanceAnnouncer class code:

```
package com.blueit.audioguide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by janeks on 23.04.2016..
 */
public class DistanceAnnouncer {
    private TextToSpeech speaker;

    public DistanceAnnouncer(Context context) {
        speaker = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    speaker.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void speak(Location targetLocation, Location currentLocation) {
        if (targetLocation == null) return;
        if (currentLocation == null) return;

        if ((!(targetLocation == null)) && (!(currentLocation == null))) {
            float distanceInMeters = targetLocation.distanceTo(currentLocation);
            if (distanceInMeters < 1000) {
                distanceInMeters = Math.round(distanceInMeters);
                speaker.speak(String.valueOf(distanceInMeters) + " meters",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            } else if ((distanceInMeters >= 1000) && (distanceInMeters <= 100000)) {
                float distanceInKilometers = distanceInMeters / 1000;
                distanceInKilometers = Math.round(distanceInKilometers * 10) / 10;
                speaker.speak(String.valueOf(distanceInKilometers) + " kilometers",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }  else if (distanceInMeters > 100000) {
                float distanceInKilometers = distanceInMeters / 1000;
                distanceInKilometers = Math.round(distanceInKilometers);
                speaker.speak(String.valueOf(distanceInKilometers) + " kilometers",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Application log, filtered by *TextToSpeech*:

```
04-23 16:00:03.911 30815-30815/com.blueit.audioguide I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
04-23 16:00:03.988 30815-30815/com.blueit.audioguide I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
04-23 16:00:03.995 30815-30932/com.blueit.audioguide I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
04-23 16:01:35.048 30815-30815/com.blueit.audioguide I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
04-23 16:01:44.346 30815-30815/com.blueit.audioguide W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
```

Seems like the system connects first one to system TTS service but not the second one. But for what reason? I also tried removing first one and leave only second (maybe several TTS per Activity are not allowed?), but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep the one `DistanceAnnouncer` instance as a member variable of `MainActivity`.

The problem with always creating a new instance in the `AlertDialog` is that the TTS engine is not instantly available. Now you call...

```
DistanceAnnouncer newDistanceAnnouncer = new DistanceAnnouncer(MainActivity.this);

//THIS DOESN'T WORK:                    
newDistanceAnnouncer.speak(mTargetLocation,mCurrentLocation);
```

...which then tries to speak trough the TTS engine before it has been properly initialized i.e. before `onInit()` has run.